# How to download multiple files from minio server in java by passing bucket name and file name

Tags: java, minio

How to download multiple files from minio server in java by passing bucket name and file name.
Suppose one bucket is having file abc1.txt and abc2.text
and so on.I want to get more then one file.

Comment: in python we are use client.list_objects(bucket.name,recursive=True) and recursive=True will return all files and folders name. something like this maybe been in java

Answer (score 0):

There are no bulk downloads with the single request in S3 API, you should call `GetObject` for each object. You may call `GetObject` in parallel.

Comment: that only I was using thought there might be something, but I think no. Anyways Thank you :)